# GSAP animation not working in tabbed menu

Tags: jquery, gsap

So I've tried to use GSAP to animate elements that have been triggered by their corresponding buttons. The animation itself works, but instead of revealing the corresponding element, it reveals all of them. I've attached a [working codepen here](http://codepen.io/modermo/pen/KzobQb?editors=0010)

```
var trigger = ".trigger";
var recipient = ".target";
var animation = new TimelineMax({reversed:true, paused:true});



$(trigger).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  recipient = '#' + $(this).attr('data-target-id');
  if($(trigger).hasClass("active")){
    $(trigger).not(this).removeClass("active");
  }

  if($(".target").hasClass("open")){
    $not_recipient = $(".target").not(recipient);
    $(".target").not(recipient).removeClass("open");
  }

  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $(recipient).toggleClass("open");

  animation.fromTo(recipient, .3, {display:'none', y:'-100%', autoAlpha:0},{display:'block',y:'0%', autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut});
  animation.reversed() ? animation.play() : animation.reverse();
 });
```

Comment: something like this: **[codepen](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/NNZYyW?editors=0010)**?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `TimelineMax`, you can do it by `TweenMax`.

**Updated js**

```
var trigger = ".trigger";
var recipient = ".target";
var animation;


$(trigger).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(! $(this).hasClass('active')){
        var parentElm = $(this).parent();
        var targetChild = parentElm.find(recipient);

        $(trigger).removeClass('active');
        $(recipient).removeClass('open');

        $(this).addClass('active');
        targetChild.addClass('open');

        if(animation){
            animation.reverse();
        }
        animation = TweenMax.fromTo(targetChild, .3, {display:'none', y:'-100%', autoAlpha:0},{display:'block',y:'0%', autoAlpha:1, ease:Power1.easeOut});

    }

});
```

[Updated Demo](http://codepen.io/shishirmorshed/pen/oxrdvQ)

Comment: The basic functionality is there, yes, but the reason there is a click to toggle class is so that if the user presses the trigger again, the element reverses. 

Also, the html has been very strictly organized in that fashion for a structural reason – your codepen has moved some of the elements around.

Comment: The OP used TimelineMax so he didn't have to create a new tweens on every click. In GSAP it is better to create the timeline outside of your event handlers. And then just simply play() and reverse() the animation. This way you are not creating unnecessary new tweens on every click which can help with performance and GC. :)